# Angular Firebase calls as a service

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm seeking to know what would be best practice, when developing an Angular application with Firebase as a backend. Most tutorials and alike doesn't use firebase calls as a service, but run them directly in the component.
Is this how you should handle using firebase in angular?
since i'm thinking it would be more usefull to make services to fetch/update certain data on Firebase, since it would be reuseable across multiple components.

also, if you have any litterature or links on using firebase as a service (angular4 with Angularfire2), It would be greatly apprecieated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling the firebase exclusively from services and not directly in the components is definitely a good thing. It will make it easier to maintain your firebase calls and avoid duplicated code. And dependency injection in Angular will help you a lot.

If you want some inspiration you can check out this [repository](https://github.com/jonas99y/pythagorasvo21). Have a look at [this](https://github.com/jonas99y/pythagorasvo21/tree/master/src/app/shared/services) folder where we have multiple services each responsible for a different part of the data.

Comment: Thanks Jonas Wyss. This was exactly what i was looking for!